# Access contents of an array of character pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays

If I want to access a string that I stored on a n array of characters pointer and assign that string to another variable, how can I do this? Here what I have:

```
printf("Number of words in the list: ");
scanf("%d", &no_words);
char *words[no_words];

for (int i = 0; i < no_words; ++i)
{
    words[i] = (char *)malloc((10 + 1)*sizeof(char));
    printf("Word #%d:\n", i +1);
    scanf("%s", words[i]);
    printf("%s", words[i]);         
}
```

I'm able to print the strings that I get from user input, but I want to do something like the following to loop thru each character of the string.

```
char[11] test= words[i]
```

Comment: You already know how to loop through an array, you do it with `words`. While`words[i]` is a pointer it points to an "array" in memory that you can loop over just like any other array. The important thing to know when looping through the "array" pointed to by `word[i]` is that it might be shorter than the amount or memory you allocated for it.

Comment: By the way, you might want to instruct `scanf` to not write beyond the end of the memory you allocated for it, by using e.g. `"%10s"`.

Comment: `char[11] test` is not valid C. Your code works fine. I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Finally, why are you dynamically allocating memory when you always use a fixed length? Why not simply declare `words` as an array of arrays? Like `char words[no_words][11]`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I used the fixed length for testing purposes, but it's going to be dynamically varying depending on the user's input. Thanks for the response, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @M.M I wanted to loop thru each string that the user entered.

Comment: Your code already does that (see the `for` loop)

Answer (score 1):

> *loop thru each character of the string*

You already have a pointer to the string, now just like you looped for the array of pointers, you can do for the elements also.

For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < no_words; ++i)
    {
        words[i] = malloc(10 + 1);  //sizeof(char) ==1 in C
                                   // Also, why not check for malloc() success?
        printf("Word #%d:\n", i +1);
        scanf("%10s", words[i]);     //making safe from buffer overflow
        printf("%s", words[i]);     
        int len = strlen(words[i]);

             for (int cnt = 0; cnt < len; cnt++)
             {
                  printf("%c\t", words[i][cnt]);
             }
               printf("\n");
    }
```

Here, the `words[i][cnt]` will give you the access to each individual element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are not far off, knowing that you are reserving `10` characters per string allows you to allocate memory in a single call to handle all input by declaring `no_words` number of `char (*words)[11];` rather than allocating `no_words` pointers and then allocating for each word added to the list in the loop. E.g.:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAXC = 10 };

int main (void)
{
    char (*words)[MAXC+1] = {NULL};
    char test[MAXC+1] = {0};
    int i, no_words;

    printf ("Number of words in the list: ");
    scanf ("%9d%*c", &no_words);

    if (!(words = calloc (no_words, sizeof *words))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < no_words; i++) {
        printf (" enter word[%d]: ", i+1);
        scanf ("%9[^\n]%*c", words[i]);
    }

    printf ("\nWords colected in the list:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < no_words; i++)
        printf ("  word[%d] : %s\n", i, words[i]);

    strcpy (test, words[no_words > 1 ? no_words - 2 : 0]);
    printf ("\n test : %s\n\n", test);

    free (words);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Use**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_words
Number of words in the list: 9
 enter word[1]: the
 enter word[2]: quick
 enter word[3]: brown
 enter word[4]: fox
 enter word[5]: jumps
 enter word[6]: over
 enter word[7]: a
 enter word[8]: lazy
 enter word[9]: dog

Words colected in the list:

  word[0] : the
  word[1] : quick
  word[2] : brown
  word[3] : fox
  word[4] : jumps
  word[5] : over
  word[6] : a
  word[7] : lazy
  word[8] : dog

 test : lazy
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any additional questions.